# No background in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I've recently designed a website and have realised that some of the background of the content, when you scroll down is transparent and so the fixed div that is beneath the content displays on IE and Firefox. Please see [my website](http://kadeem.london) for a live view of the problem. The HTML is below. Please see below an image of my problem as you can see the text "Get In Touch" is being displayed. I want the background of the content to be above this. Please find attached the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkxu2erj/1/).

```
<body>
<div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
<button type=button class=overlay-close></button>
<img src=http://kadeem.london/Image/Transparent-Kadeem-min.png class="fixed-Me scaling">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href=http://kadeem.london>Home</a></li>
<li><a href=papers.html>Papers</a></li>
<li><a href=events.html>Events</a></li>
<li><a href=designs.html>Designs</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id=trigger-overlay>
<div class=menubutton>
<h3 class=menubuttontext>MENU</h3></div></div>
<div class=high-container>
<div class=global-container>
<div class=Intro-Video>
<div class=video-box>
<div id=video-container>
<video autoplay class=fillWidth>
<source src=Video/Trailer.mp4 type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
<div class=Kadeem-Logo>
<img src=http://kadeem.london/Image/KL-LOGO.png>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class=content-container>
<div class=row>
<div class="border red"></div>
<h1 class=title-role>
I'm Kadeem
</h1>
</div>
<div class=post-container>
<div class=Biographical-Content>
<div class="step out-view"></div>
<br>
<p>I go by the name of <a href=https://www.linkedin.com>Kadeem</a>. I am an events graduate currently developing an events marketing start-up. This website was created from scratch using HTML5, CSS3,jQuery & responsive design. I specialise in event management, digital content, SEO, marketing strategy, branding and front-end web design. <p> Freedom of thought inspires me. I love conceptualising and seeing ideas evolve. I see myself as a marketeer who simply likes to make things look good, branding has thus always been my most favourable aspect of marketing. I studied event management in university and have organised a <a href=events.html> few events</a> of my own. I am currently working as an event organiser at <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spire_Healthcare>Spire Healthcare</a>. I hope to integrate events within marketing strategy more. I like to ask the <a href=http://stackoverflow.com/users/1923610/kadeem- target=_blank>right questions</a> and find solutions from different perspectives. My academic interests lie in the regions of city branding and <a href=https://www.academia.edu/14690454/The_Commercial_and_Political_Implications_of_Events>events management.</a> <p>My favourite book is <a href=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince>The Prince</a> by Nicolo Machievelli. My favourite dish is <a href=http://lifestyle.sapo.pt/sabores/receitas/arroz-de-marisco>Arroz De Marisco.</a> This website has been recently created so content is being added concurrently.
<p>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class=other-contain>
<div class=My-Gems>
<div id=effect-6 class="effects clearfix">
<div class=img>
<img src=https://alchetron.com/cdn/zeebra-5e766eb1-964a-49c5-b888-c05effa9354-resize-750.jpeg style=height:100% alt>
<div class=overlay5>
<a class=expand>Bone & Joint Launch</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class=img>
<img src=http://kadeem.london/Image/Money-Matters-Logo.png alt>
<div class=overlay5>
<a href=designs.html class=expand>Money Matters</a>
</div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class=eee>
<div class=row>
<section id=activities class=pane>
<div class=pane-content>
<div class=pane-row>
<div class=summary>
<p>POSTS</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pane-row d">
<div class=activity-col>
<h4>city branding</h4>
<ul>
<li><a>The Impact of City Branding in The Perceived Image of Cities: The Case of New York City</a></li>
</ul>
<h4>Urban Regeneration</h4>
<ul>
<li>The Role of Events in Urban Regeneration</li>
<li>Hacknified</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class=activity-col>
<h4>Marketing Strategy</h4>
<ul>
<li>Marketing Strategy: British Airways vs. Air France</li>
<li>The Marketing Strategies of Startup Brands</li>
</ul>
<h4>Events Management</h4>
<ul>
<li>The Political & Commerical Implications of Events</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class=activity-col>
<h4>Events Marketing</h4>
<ul>
<li>Marketing Events Online</li>
<li>The Role of City Branding in Urban Tourism</li>
</ul>
<h4>Digital Marketing</h4>
<ul>
<li>Digital Content</li>
<li>Post Purchase Behaviour of Hotel Guests</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
<footer class=goodbye>
<div class="border red4"></div>
<div class=block>
<div class=centered>
<h2 class=text-go>GET IN TOUCH</h2>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
<footer class=goodbye4>
<div class=block6>
<div class=centered6>
If you would like to find out more about me you can <a href=mailto:redacted>message me</a>.
</div>
</div>
</footer>
<footer class=goodbye5>
<div class=container1>
<footer class=footer>
<div class=container1>
<div class=flex-item>© 2015 KADEEM</div>
</div>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the complete code, or make a working snippet or fiddle to view the problem. With your html we can't see anything.https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I think we need CSS to see te problem

Comment: Hello sorry, I've now popped in the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an empty `P` tag inside your `post-container` that is causing this gap. Remove it and it will fix everything accross all browsers. Also, once the empty tag is removed, you could give the last `P` element (with the "My favourite book" text) a padding-bottom of 45px to push the container down correctly.

```
<div class="post-container">
<div class="Biographical-Content hidden visible animated fadeInUpBig">
<div style="height: 407px;" class="step out-view active"></div>
<br>
<p>I go by the name of [...]</p>
<p> Freedom of thought [...]</p>
<p>My favourite book [...]</p>
<p></p> --> Empty P tag
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If for any reason you can't avoid having that "extra" `<p>` in your html; add this to your css

```
p:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```